# Notice: Undefined index: inter in C:\wamp\www\serp-tracker\index.php on line 141/144/147/150

Tags: php

how could i remove this error i just trying but i can't found any solution for this. this is the exactly code which i'm using but that one error intrpting.

```
$abfrage = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM fsom_keywords WHERE active = 1",$link);
while ( $daten = @mysql_fetch_array($abfrage)){ 
    echo'<tr><td>';
    echo utf8_encode($daten['keyword']);
    echo'</td>';
    echo'<td>';
    echo $tage7[utf8_encode($daten['keyword'])];
    echo'</td>';
    echo'<td>';
    echo $tage1[utf8_encode($daten['keyword'])];
    echo'</td>';
    echo'<td>';
    echo $tage0[utf8_encode($daten['keyword'])];
    echo'</td>';
    echo'<td>';
    if($tage1[utf8_encode($daten['keyword'])]!="" && $tage0[utf8_encode($daten['keyword'])]!="")
{
    echo $tage1[utf8_encode($daten['keyword'])] - $tage0[utf8_encode($daten['keyword'])];
    }
    echo'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
    }}  
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` will remove notices. But I believe that you should solve the problem - I believe that $daten['keyword'] equals 'inter' and $tage1['inter'] doesn't defined.

Comment: Remove the `@` on the second line, then you can fix the errors.

Comment: the error lines are echo $tage1/8/7/0[utf8_encode($daten['keyword'])]

Comment: @DanishIqbal what the issue you are getting now

Answer (score 0):

you should check values using `isset()` before echoing

```
echo isset($daten['keyword'])?$daten['keyword']:"";
```

Comment: $daten['keyword'] might be set, but $tage0[$daten['keyword']] might not.

Comment: i appritiate your any type of help and i tried  isset but still not working